# Regular expression to exclude a specific string?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that matches `picture.jpg` or `picture.png`, but not `picture.gif`

Currently I have:

`^(picture)+[.]+(jpg|png)`

And I've tried appending `(?!gif)`, which doesn't seem to do the trick.

How would I exclude file types that are `.gif`?

Comment: Your current regex will not match `.gif`. See [here](http://regex101.com/r/dI2hN5/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are matching a list of items you do not have to exclude items that are not in that list. Think about it. If you are trying to match "a", "b" and "c" then  there is no reason to make sure that "d" is not matched also. It will never be matched because that is not what you are trying to match.

```
/^picture\.(?:jpg|png)$/
```

This will match file names that:

1. Start with "picture"
2. Have a "." after that
3. And are terminated by either "jpg" or "png"

The `(?:)` thing is a [*non-capturing group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

If you also want to match "jpeg" then you can use this:

```
/^picture\.(?:jpe?g|png)$/
```

The `e?` just means that "e" is allowed but not required.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot of sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
^picture\.(?:jpg|png)$
```

Here is a [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wR7qD8/1)

If you specifically want to exclude `.gif` but match any other extension, use a negative lookbehind:

```
^(picture\.[\w]{3}(?<!\.gif))$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wR7qD8/4)